# Unable to trigger Bulk SMS using Twilio Notify API

Tags: java, twilio, notify, bulksms

I have to create a functionality where I must send same SMS text to multiple numbers in an array. For that I am using Notify API. As part of the requirement I created a Notify Service and Messaging Service with the existing number used for normal sms service and linked them up under my Trail Twilio Account.

Wrote the code, as present in the docs and tested over a API hit. The code executed successfully and on the twilio logs, it is coming as sent. But I am not able to receive any sms notification on the number provided.

Where am I going wrong??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a [Twilio trial account](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360036052753-Twilio-Free-Trial-Limitations), there are certain limitations. Can you look under your [debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/debugger?quickDate=72) (the bug icon in the upper right corner of your Twilio Console) to see if there any are any events?

Also, once you upgrade your account, verify [SMS geographic permissions](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/settings/geo-permissions) are set for the destinations you are trying to send messages to

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, Even though I used debugger earlier, which was basically prompting me to connect my Notify API with Messaging Service. There were no new errors. But it was basically 2 issues:
1) My Messaging Service had no trial phoneNumber linked.
2) In Notify SMS Geographic Permissions My Home Country is not selected.

Rectifying these 2 errors solved my problem of not receiving Bulk SMS Messages on my phone.